# How to Add Custom Button to Text(HTML) Editor and NOT Visual Editor

Tags: theme-development, visual-editor, html-editor

I followed [this tutorial](http://qnimate.com/adding-buttons-to-wordpress-visual-editor/) which is adding a custom button into `Visual Editor` as it is supposed to. But this is not adding the button into  the `Text(HTML)` Editor. Can you please let me know how I can add my own button into `Text(HTML)` Editor only (or at least both! and not Visual one)

```
function enqueue_plugin_scripts($plugin_array)
{
    //enqueue TinyMCE plugin script with its ID.
    $plugin_array["green_button_plugin"] =  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "index.js";
    return $plugin_array;
}

add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "enqueue_plugin_scripts");

function register_buttons_editor($buttons)
{
    //register buttons with their id.
    array_push($buttons, "green");
    return $buttons;
}

add_filter("mce_buttons", "register_buttons_editor");
```